# How to backup-restore my data

Tags: restore, reinstall

I broke my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when I tried to do something with my Graphic Drivers. When I am using application which is in full-screen mode my computer is freezing. I think the only way to repair system is make  reinstall. The problem is I want to save my data. I did the backup of my home directory using built-in tool. Is it possible to recover data from backup after reinstalling the system?

I am sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All settings and app settings are stored in /home/ folder.
If you don't format the disk everything will remain there. 
If you format the disk,
Copy /home folder in a external usb and after installing ubuntu paste /home into /home.
As for the apps and executables, you better

```
sudo apt install <app name>
```

them. Otherwise if you copy paste them to restore them too, you might break something again.